# Set Minimum Percent Height for Layout inside Constraint Layout

Tags: android, view, android-constraintlayout, android-cardview

I have one `ConstraintLayout` which has one `View` & `CardView`. CardView is `75%` of total layout and `25%` is other View. CardView contains some views which looks good in normal screens. When Font size is increased the overlapping of views inside CardView is seen. How can we achieve this as set Minimum Height in `%` for a View inside ConstraintLayout. So that if there is overlapping in inside views the view height will be pushed up maintaining the minimum 75%.

Comment: can you please put your layout code?

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one *app:layout_constraintHeight_min* or *app:layout_constraintGuide_percent* at the same time. If you want to combine both of them, you can set height of CardView manually in your **onCreate** method.

```
constraintLayout.post {
    cardView.minimumHeight = (constraintLayout.height * 0.75).toInt()
}
```

Comment: Not able to find post method on ConstraintLayout

Comment: post method belongs to View, therefore you can call this method any View including ConstraintLayout.

Comment: However, i code wrote in Kotlin. If you use Java, the code may be changed little bit.